# How to configure Lint to ignore google-services.json?

Tags: android, android-lint, google-play-services

How should Lint be configured to ignore the Firebase config file, particularly spell check? The google-services.json file is in the "app" module folder.

```
build.gradle (app)

    lintOptions {
        lintConfig file('lint.xml')
    }
```

The following lint.xml file is definitely being picked up by Lint as the RtlHardcoded check is disabled successfully, but Lint still spellchecks the Firebase json file and lists several entries under the "Typos" heading in the Lint report.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="RtlHardcoded" severity="ignore" />

    <issue id="Typos">
        <ignore path="/google-services.json" />
        <ignore path="/app/google-services.json" />
        <ignore path="**/google-services.json" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

How do I specify the ignore path so Lint ignores the Firebase google-services.json file?

Comment: Spell checking is not a Android Lint check, it is Intellij IDEA check, which is not part of Android Lint, so `lint.xml` is not supported in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom scope for spelling check:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-scopes.html

And then configure spelling scopes via `Editor / Inspections` menu:

[image]